# Python: 'if not any' using a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
if not any(myList[0:5]):
```

does this also work with a dictionary instead of a list?
I want to check if the first five key-value-pairs of my dictionary all have the value 'False'.

Comment: What does it mean for a key-value pair to "have the value `False`"? A key-value pair *is a pair*, i.e. a tuple of 2 things. A tuple cannot have the value `False` because a tuple is not even the same kind of thing that `False` is. Also, "the first five" is not a meaningful concept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, dictionary keys are not ordered. You can't say "the first five keys" of a dictionary and mean something well-defined. You can get a list of the keys, in which case they will of course be ordered in that list, but that doesn't say anything about the "order" in the dictionary itself.

What you can do is check all keys in a list to see if the corresponding value in the dictionary is `False`:

```
the_dict = { "k1": True, "k2": False, "k3": False, "k4": True, "k5": False, "k6": True }
check_keys = ["k1", "k2", "k3", "k4", "k5"]
found = 0
for k in check_keys:
  if k in the_dict and not the_dict[k]:
    found += 1
print "Found %u False values for the checked keys" % found
```

Notice that just because there is an order to the key-value pairs in the dictionary literal when initializing `the_dict`, that doesn't mean that order somehow remains in the dictionary itself.

If your keys are sortable, you can of course sort them manually and then extract the five first:

```
>>> print sorted(the_dict.keys()[:5]
['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4', 'k5']
```

Comment: but instead of [0:5], can i use the keys that i want to check? how would this look like?

Answer (score 10):

if you have a list of keys you want to check, use a generator expression:

```
if not any(myDict[key] for key in myKeys):
```

Answer (score 0):

you asking for this:

```
if not any(myDict.values()[0:5]):
```

as undefined as it maybe that's what you asked for

Answer (score 0):

If you need ordering in the dictionary, you can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict()
for key in range(5):
    d[key] = False
d[6] = True

# This following check will succeed                                       
if not any(d.values()[:5]):
    print 'First five values are False'
```